# Converting from factor to date in R

Tags: r, date, na

I'm reading in my data as characters, like so:

```
gc <- read.csv("C:/Users/name/Documents/folder 1/folder 2/folder 3/gc_data1.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I can `gc$date` to check that the dates are all there and look good, as characters. Now the problem arises when I try to convert them to dates:

```
gc$date <- as.Date(gc$date, format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

I try to use the "`as.Date`" function and some of them become "`NA`". Console rows [1-56] and [381-446] are converted properly (date showing as yyyy-mm-dd: 2016-12-09, and 2016-07-11 respectively) and the rest show NA.

What is going on here and how can I convert all of the dates from characters to dates?

Data is from an excel sheet saved as a csv, looks like this (the date and plot change):

|plot|date|
|------|--------|
|Mi13| 9/19/2016|
|Mi23| 9/19/2016|
|So14| 10/26/2016|
|Mi12| 11/21/2016|

Comment: Please post a sample of your data.

Comment: We cannot see your data, so it is difficult to help you.

Comment: Okay! I added a snippet of my data in a crude way, is there else I should do to share my data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your data:

```
R> dt <- as.factor(c("9/19/2016", "9/19/2016", "10/26/2016", "11/21/2016"))
R> dt
[1] 9/19/2016  9/19/2016  10/26/2016 11/21/2016
Levels: 10/26/2016 11/21/2016 9/19/2016
R>
```

Second, using `anydate()` function from the [anytime](https://cran.r-project.org/package=anytime) package -- which can, among other things, work directly on factors:

```
R> library(anytime)
R> anydate(dt)
[1] "2016-09-19" "2016-09-19" "2016-10-26" "2016-11-21"
R>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data is in month/day/year format but you are using day/month/year for the format string.  If you fix that it works:

```
x <- as.factor(c("9/19/2016", "9/19/2016", "10/26/2016", "11/21/2016")) 

as.Date(x, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
## [1] "2016-09-19" "2016-09-19" "2016-10-26" "2016-11-21"
```